# D3js Line graph with Nested Json Data

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I am new to d3js and was checking for previous solutions and have been trying them without success for my issue.
My line graph [has the out put as this enclosed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir6rX.jpg)
the structure of my data after applying d3.nest () on 2 dimensions, is {"10":86,"14",114}. I am plotting the keys("10") in the x axis and the values:86 in the Y axis. My scales are defined as follows:

```
    var x =d3.scale.ordinal()
             .rangeBands([0, width])   
       .domain(["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"
                   ,    
             "13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear() 
              .range([height,0])
              .domain([0, d3.max(grpdata, function(d) { 
                                                        return d.values; 

                                                      })]);
```

I tried converting the key to string as well.

```
     var valueline = d3.svg.line()
                       .x(function(d) { 
                                        return (d.key).toString() ; 

                                     }) 
                      .y(function(d) { 
                                        return y(d.values);
                                    });
```

Is there a way to properly display the chart so it extends to the end of the x scale. Any help is much appreciated thank you

Comment: from what you have pasted everything looks OK. I think best is if you can provide your tried code and data in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot cyril for your comment. I am adding the code which is part of a bigger code and is within the d3.json function.

Comment: Looks like cant post my full code in here..

Comment: Please make a bl.ock with your code.  I find blockbuilder.org to be a convenient fiddle for d3.